# Have ever done before and ever did before

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between

a) I've done a lot of exercise in my life, but I've done more in the last few days than ***I've ever done before***.

b) I've done a lot of exercise in my life, but I've done more in the last few days than ***I ever did before***.

Thank you.

Comment: cross-posted here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/89277/have-ever-done-before-or-ever-did-before

Answer (score 1):

I've done a lot of exercise in my life, but I've done more in the last few days than I've ever done before..

'before' is used either with Present Perfect or Past Perfect, not Simple Past

I'd never tried sushi before, so I decided to try it.
I've never tried sushi before, so I've decided to try it.